# Using TempData with returnview()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two ***ActionResults*** and I am trying to just simply pass an int id from one ***ActionResult*** to another. I attempted to use ***tempdata***, but after looking at the value from the debugger the value was zero. The tempdata example I looked at used ***redirecttoaction()***. Can this be done with ***returnview()***?

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
         myEMSurvey mySurvey = db.myEMSurveys.Find(id);
        if (mySurvey == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        SurveyViewModel svm = new SurveyViewModel();
        svm.mySurvey = mySurvey;
        svm.Questions = (from s in db.myEMSurveyQuestions
                         where s.SurveyID == id
                         select s).ToList();
        svm.Options = (from o in db.myEMQuestionOptions
                       where o.SurveyID == id
                       select o).ToList();
        svm.Anwsers = (from a in db.myEMSurveyAnswers
                       where a.SurveyID == id
                       select a).ToList();
        int intid = id.Value;
        TempData["ID"] = intid;
        return View(svm);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CsvDownload()
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(TempData["ID"]); //value of id=0, TempData["ID"] = 33

        var Anwsers = (from a in db.myEMSurveyAnswers
                   where a.SurveyID == id
                   select a).ToList();
         //id = 0
    }
```

CsvDownload in Details view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("CsvDownload", "Survey", FormMethod.Post))
{
<div class="text-center">
    <input type="submit" name="button" value="Download" class="btn btn-success" />
</div>
<br />}
```

Comment: TempData only exists in the lifecycle of the current request.  It's not clear how you're calling `CsvDownload` above.  Are these two separate post backs?

Comment: TempData is only reliable and useful when redirecting between Action methods.  You can consider using a Session variable or Hidden inputs or some other construct here.

Comment: @GeorgeJohnston I have updated my question with info from my details view. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: @user2133925 the tempdata also works incase of return view , plz check the value on this line  TempData["ID"] = intid;

Comment: @Sadaquat the value of id=0 but the value of TempData["ID"] = 33. Am i converting this incorrectly?

Comment: @user2133925 you can try to convert it to int, plz check what is your value  in the view.write this in your view and see whats the value {int i=TempData["ID"].convertToInt()}

Comment: What is stopping you from adding the propety to the svm ViewModel? Seems like it belongs there (but I can't be sure without more code)

Comment: @user2133925 Also as suggested by Daniel you can pass this value using your model.Do you have some specific reason for using tempdata?

Comment: @user2133925 I could have used the viewmodel, but I came across and example using tempdata and I wanted to try to learn something new. What exactly are the pros/cons of doing it this way instead of viewmodel? Everyone seems very against tempdata/viewbag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in my code was the convert to int32.

Instead I needed to convert like so:

```
int id = (int)(TempData["ID"]);
```

This is known as "unboxing". It's a straight cast from object to int.